# AS3 dynamic variable creation in DC

Tags: actionscript-3

Can variables be created dynamically without declaration when we write as Document class in AS3?

For example, from a library I'm importing sound files. Some 20 sound files. 
If the code is in fla itself, we can assign in for loop like:

```
this["SOUND"+increasingNumber]
```

But in documentClass this is not working , since `this` refers the class here not the stage.

Any method to create variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When imported into your library, right click the sound file and go to its properties. Click the actionscript tab and check 'export for actionscript'. Give it a class name which you can then use in your document class to instantiate that sound.

If you named it Sound1:

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound1();
sound.play();
```

[more detailed info here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/)

[Edit to loxxy's reply] above shows how to create the variables in the document class.
To dynamically create all the sound variables, I'd recommend using an array, like so:

Suppose you named all your sounds in your library Sound1 to Sound20

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

var sounds:Array = [];
var soundClass:Class;
for(var i:int = 1; i<21; i++){
soundClass = getDefinitionByName("Sound" + i) as Class;
sounds.push(new soundClass());
}
```

Comment: Yeah .Thanks .  That works .  Is there any way to create n number of soundChannels?? . And want them with specific names .For ex,  If I have an array as  ["gotRight","delete","enter"]   , I want 3 three sound channels with this name ..

Answer (score 1):

In fla when you add code, you add it into a framescript.

A framescript is a block of code repeated at a regular interval (framerate).

You can achieve that using addFrameScript [like this](http://www.rblank.com/2009/10/11/adding-actionscript-dynamically-to-frames-with-addframescript-in-as3/).

However a better approach would be to not mix up framescript & the regular class methods.

You can access the 'stage' from the code but only after the added_to_stage event to be sure.

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

function init(e:Event):void{ 

     // Access 'stage' here

}
```